# USB internet sharing from Linux to iOS

Tags: linux, network-interface, internet, ios

I'm wondering if it's possible to share an internet connection from a Linux computer to an iOS device using an USB to lightning cable.

It is possible to share an internet connection from Mac OS X to an iOS device using a USB to lightning cable.

There are two use cases for this

1. faster download of pushed apps
2. if an iOS device loses its internet connection in a locked state, than it must be connected to a wired ethernet connection.

I'm assuming that number two would work in some cases if the restrictions were not too high on the MDM deployment. The tried and true method of this is an Apple digital camera adapter plugged into a Apple USB ethernet adapter and a lightning cable plugged into a USB charger.

I'm not very familiar with Linux however a preliminary Google search brought up something called
libimobiledevice
I'm not sure if it could be of use in the process of connecting internet over USB to an iOS in Linux.

Comment: Another use case is devices with broken radio modules. Did you find a solution?